# Why Bash-in-Makefile expression doesn't work?

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

Directly pasted into my shell, the following tries each of the 3 regex and works (see the `*.{jpg,png,gis.tif}`):

```
for file in ./output/India/*.{jpg,png,gis.tif}; do echo $file; openssl base64 -in $file -out ./output/India/`basename $file`.b64; done;
```

As a makefile process, it fails and returns :

```
task: 
  for file in ./output/India/*.{png,jpg,gis.tif} ; \
    do echo $$file ; openssl base64 -in $$file -out ./output/India/`basename $$file`.b64; \
  done
```

and returns :

```
47910543179104:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('./output/India/*.{png,jpg,gis.tif}','r')
```

Why this expression doesn't work when the Bash is in a makefile  ?

Comment: Just a tip: if you find yourself writing a shell `for` loop in _make_, then you are probably doing it wrong. Here you are converting a `.png` into a `.b64` (for example). That sounds like a job directly for _make_. There are many advantages in doing this: incremental builds, parallel operation, error checking...

Comment: @bobbogo: thanks for the comment, have you any practical example to show/ link so we may learn your way ? Feel free to post in an answer the way you would approach this issue, it will help goodwill learners and I will +1 for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been prompted to give a sketch of how *make* could do the heavy lifting for you.

So, you want to convert all the source files (`.jpg`, `.png`, `.gis.tif`) in `output/India/` into their base64 encoded equivalents. A sketch:

```
.PHONY: all
all: # default target

dir := output/India/
exts := jpg png gis.tif
wildcards := $(addprefix ${dir}*.,${exts})
sources := $(wildcard ${wildcards})
targets := $(addsuffix .b64,${sources})

${targets}: %.b64: %
     openssl base64 -in $< -out $@

all: ${targets}
all: ; : $@ Success
```

This is more verbose than it needs to be, and normally I rail against the use of `$(wildcard …)`. Oh well.

So what advantages do we have here over the shell version?

1. `make -j5` will do 5 conversions at once. Good if you have four CPUs
2. The conversion stops on the first error (like disk full say)
3. Files that have not changed since their last conversion are not re-converted
4. No dodgy shell syntax (though *sh* is a big part of *make*)

**UNTESTED BTW.** Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for this crash course. Personal notes: `addprefix`, `wildcard`, `addsuffix` are Make specific syntax if i get it right. `%.b64: %` removes the `.b64` extension from `${targets}`. Hard for newbee, and super interesting!

Comment: Yes, gnu _make_ comes with a handfull of functions, all accessed via the `$(funcname args)` syntax. The `%.b64: %` is actually part of a _static pattern rule_, and (in this case) succinctly expresses that a `.b64` file is out-of-date when the corresponding `%` file has changed (it _depends on_ it).

Answer (score 4):

make uses `/bin/sh` by default and it doesn't support brace expansions.

Either tell make to use a different shell by setting the `SHELL` variable inside the makefile, don't use brace expansions in the make rules, or run a script instead of an inline recipe (which script can be run by `bash`/etc.).

Comment: Ok, following your answer I went brutal on it : `for file in ./output/$(NAME)/*.png ./output/$(NAME)/*.jpg ./output/$(NAME)/*.gis.tif` :D